# Hide middle nodes in neo4j (Browser)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

My question is the following. I have the following node relationship:

```
(Student)-[:StudiesIn]->(Class)<-[:Teaches]-(Professor)
```

I'm trying to display on the graph generator in the browser a query like:

```
MATCH st=(a:Student)-[]-()-[]-(sir:Professor) RETURN st
```

Which gives me back a relationship including the class. Now I don't really care about the class for this particular visualization, and I would want to hide it. Is there any way of doing this without ACTUALLY creating (And storing on the disk) the relationship between the student and the professor?

I'd just want something like:

```
MATCH (a:Student)-[]-()-[]-(sir:Professor) RETURN (a)-[{name:"HasAsProfessor"}]-(sir)
```

But that doesn't work. I've also looked at :http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/147evnv9j2/feature-request-virtual-relationships-in-result-sets where the suggestion looks like:

```
MATCH (a:Student)-[]-()-[]-(sir:Professor) RETURN {start:a, rel:"CustomRel", end:sir}
```

But that didn't work in the browser (And I don't have time to re-implement a graph visualization tool from scratch)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the procedure to create [virtual relationships from the APOC library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_virtual_nodes_rels):

```
MATCH st=(S:Student)-[:StudiesIn]->(:Class)<-[:Teaches]-(P:Professor)
WITH S, collect(distinct P) as PS
UNWIND PS as P
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(S,'HasAsProfessor',{}, P) YIELD rel
RETURN S, rel, P
```

**Upd**: To display in the neo4j-browser is suitable simple trick to create and immediately delete the relationship:

```
MATCH st=(S:Student)-[:StudiesIn]->(:Class)<-[:Teaches]-(P:Professor)
WITH S, collect(distinct P) as PS
UNWIND PS as P
MERGE (S)-[r:VirtualRelationHasAsProfessor]->(P)
DELETE r
RETURN S, r, P
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there no way of doing this without a library? I have no access to GitHub in my workplace.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I thought about creating and deleting (Although that one's nicer that the one I had in mind).

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtual relationships from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), which are only for display and not saved in the db:

```
MATCH (a:Student)-[*2]-(sir:Professor) 
RETURN a, sir, apoc.create.vRelationship(a,'HasAsProfessor',{}, sir) as rel
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there no way of doing this without a library? I have no access to GitHub in my workplace.

Comment: @Myxoh Neo4j cannot natively create virtual graph elements, to my knowledge, APOC is your best bet here.

Comment: Thank you. for the help!